# Query archaic DB with entity framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have inherited a very old DB and I'm just starting out with .NET Core 3 (preview) to see if I can create a proof-of-concept WebApi that uses EF Core to query the DB.

So my problem is that in this DB, much of the data is untrimmed (so has lots of white space around values).  There's a mix of varchar(n) and char(n) fields.  And no, I'm not in a position to re-engineer this.

So my challenge is that the WebApi will receive a query which will contain a List<People>, and I need to return all relevant data about those people.

If I were doing this in SQL I guess I would do something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON RTRIM(LTRIM(Table1.[P1])) = RTRIM(LTRIM(Table2.[P9]))
```

I need to be able to do something similar using Entity Framework where I would join the DB table with the .NET List<People>.  However, I'm a) not sure how best to go about this with the necessary trims and b) the number of rows in this DB is very large and so it has to be a set-based operation performed on the SQL Server - I can't bring everything back to the DB and join in-memory.

**[EDIT (24th June)]**

To add some examples of what I've tried, and to re-focus the question onto the approach I should be employing:

1 - I attempted this using a JOIN

```
var y = from a in query
    join b in request.Items 
    on new { a.Prop1, a.Prop2 } equals new { b.Prop1, b.Prop2 }
    select new { a.Prop1, a.Prop2, a.Prop3 };

return await y.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The compile error returned is:

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. 
>   Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

Not sure why, but I suspect that this is because I'm trying to join strings to DB char fields.

Also tried:

```
var y = from a in query
    from b in request.Items
    where a.Prop1 == b.Prop1 && a.Prop2 == b.Prop2
    select new {a.Prop1, a.Prop2, a.Prop3};
return await y.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This compiles, but gives run-time error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'collection selector was not
>   NavigationExpansionExpression'

So, yes, I do need to be able to ensure that I'm trimming the data when doing the "join", but I think the main problem is that this needs to be a server-side operation (because of the size of the data sets) but I'd doing a join with a DB table against an in-memory List on the Client.

Not sure what the best approach is here (with EF Core 3).

Comment: What have you tried? LINQ to SQL/EF should convert the C# `String.Trim()` method into the SQL `LTRIM(RTRIM())` expression: `where t1.p1.Trim() == t2.p9.Trim()`.

Comment: Anything preventing you from replacing the fields with trimmed versions? If you can't do that, perhaps create a database view that trims.